# Kinematic parameters naming

Tags: ros2, moveit, ros-humble

When loading config files for `move_group`, it expects the kinematics to be loaded as a dict of type

```py
{"robot_description_kinematics": self.kinematics}
```

On the other hand I have built my own node that calls to MoveIt Task Constructor and MoveIt itself to create a PlanningScene and plan some movements. This node expects the kinematics as:

```py
{"_kinematics": self.kinematics}
```

Otherwise, RobotModelLoader it will complain that no kinematic is loaded, and address me to fill kinematics.yaml

***Why there is this difference in parameter naming depending on how is MoveIt used?*** I've been checking the source code but I can't find where the name of said parameter is set.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was creating RobotModelLoader like this

```cpp
        const std::string robot_urdf = this->get_parameter("robot_description").as_string();
        const std::string robot_srdf = this->get_parameter("robot_description_semantic").as_string();
        robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader::Options options(robot_urdf, robot_srdf);
        auto robot_model_loader = std::make_shared<robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader>(node_ptr, options);
```

Apparently, calling this RobotModelLoader::Options constructor sets the "robot_description_" internal attribute to "", instead of the default value set in the other constructor ("robot_description"). This attribute is used to name the parameters.

Comment: I filled an issue in github as I think this is a bug, or at least a very confusing behaviour: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/2407